# Calculating after how many purchases a customer becomes loyal (sticky)

Tags: probability, survival, churn, customer-lifetime-value

I have a dataset of customer purchase history and whether or not they have churned.

This is live data so for the customers who are still active we don't know if/when they will eventually churn.

I been asked to find the golden/MAGIC number of transactions after which a customer becomes loyal (locked into the business - EDIT: making 1 purchase a month for 3 consecutive months). Another way of phrasing is the point at which a customer becomes loyal based on number of transactions. EG: after 5 purchases a customer is 90% more likely to be loyal.

Can anyone suggest some models that might be appropriate for this line of investigation?

I'm worried that any sort of descriptive analysis (EG the average number of purchases of our loyal customers) will not be statistically significant as loyal customers will naturally have higher purchase histories and will be skewed.

Ideal Output (example):

After 1 Purchase - 20% likelihood of locking in.

After 2 Purchases - 40% likelihood of locking in.

After 3 Purchases - 5% likelihood of locking in.

So knowing this data we'd push to make sure all our customers made that second purchase.

Comment: You might start by clarifying what your definition of "locked into the business" is. If you aren't sure about how exactly to define someone as "locked into the business", you won't be able to figure out how many transactions are needed to become "locked in". And, if your definition of being "locked in" is that a person made x number of purchases, you probably don't need to do a separate analysis to determine how many purchases cause being "locked in".

Comment: hey @clementzach thanks for the reply. We'd classify someone who is locked in as being having made a purchase every month for 3 consecutive months. So our question was is there a magic number of purchases after which a customer starts to display this 'locked in' behaviour. For example I could make a purchase this month and then another in 5 months time and then begin my 'locked in' behaviour so in my case it took 2 purchases for me to get locked in. I wanted to see was there a model that could calculate this for me based on all our customer data.